# Is there any difference between object.__setattr__() and directly set?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

In werkzeug, we see:

```
class Local(object):
    __slots__ = ('__storage__', '__ident_func__')

    def __init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})
```

So, may I use `self.__storage__ = {}` to replace `object.__setattr__(self, '__storage__', {})`, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same class defines a [*custom* `__setattr__` method](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/d824659abe95ed31b1f9c355f88c4741da5a6e5f/src/werkzeug/local.py#L76-L82) that stores values *in* `self.__storage__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    ident = self.__ident_func__()
    storage = self.__storage__
    try:
        storage[ident][name] = value
    except KeyError:
        storage[ident] = {name: value}
```

However, you first need to *set an initial empty dictionary*, so the `object.__setattr__` method is used to bypass the custom one.

If you were to use `self.__storage__ = {}` then the above custom method would be called and that would lead to an attribute error, as `self.__storage__` doesn't exist yet. Or rather, it'd lead to an infinite recursion issue, as the [custom `__getattr__` method](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/d824659abe95ed31b1f9c355f88c4741da5a6e5f/src/werkzeug/local.py#L70-L74) would repeatedly be called to resolve the missing `__storage__` attribute.